# Asp Core 3.0 - Program.Main and Startup not called until a request is made

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm building an ASP Core 3.0 Api with SPA. I'm trying to add a bagkground service using AddHostedService:

```
  public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
  {

     var builder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
          .UseStartup<Startup>()
          .ConfigureServices((hostingContext, services) =>
          {
             //Add scheduled update
             services.AddHostedService<ScheduledUpdateService>();
          });

     return builder;
  }
```

The problem is that the service is not automatically started when I hit Run in Visual Studio. This is because although the server appears to be running, the Program.Main method has not been called yet. If I send a HTTP request to the server, Program.Main does get called.

Is this something that will happen when I deploy or is it just something that happens when I run the server in visual studio?

Comment: That's just how IIS and ISS Express work: https://www.taithienbo.com/how-to-auto-start-and-keep-an-asp-net-core-web-application-and-keep-it-running-on-iis/.

Comment: Share us a screen shot about your debug windows in VS. If you put a breakpoint before hit Run,the `services.AddHostedService<ScheduledUpdateService>();` should be hit.

Comment: Thanks @KirkLarkin. Am I right in saying this will only work when I deploy the app and not during development because VS uses IIS Express?

Comment: It depends on whether you’re using IIS in Production.